# Should I delete vector<short>?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, dll, visual-studio-2017

I have the following code to pass the values of a float vector. The vector holds audio data. 
However, the receiving object expects a temporary vector, so I convert the floats to shorts, then pass this vector along:

```
HRESULT CApp::PassAudio(ISpTTSEngineSite * pOutputSite, const SPVTEXTFRAG * uFragList, vector<float>&uFloats,int &uSamplesWritten)
{
    vector<short>nShortsFromFloats;
    nShortsFromFloats.resize(uFloats.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)uFloats.size(); i++)
    {
        nShortsFromFloats[i] = (int)(uFloats[i] * 32767);
    }

    //Pass the audio (shorts now!) back to the requesting site
    ULONG iSizeShorts = nShortsFromFloats.size();
    uSamplesWritten += (iSizeShorts * 2);
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = pOutputSite->Write((short *)&nShortsFromFloats[0], (iSizeShorts * 2), NULL);

    if (hr == S_OK)
    {
        //fine :-)
    }
    else
    {
        //some warning
    }

    return hr;
}
```

I would like to know if I need to delete the vector afterwards or if this is done automatically.

I'm not sure which other info is needed. I'm using this code in a DLL.

Thank you.

Comment: Side note on `vector`. `vector`s job is to hide dynamic allocation from you, so dynamically allocating one is usually a mistake. If you find someone allocating a `vector` with `new`, they either ran into a very interesting and rare problem or they are making a mistake.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is an _answer_ and, as such, belongs in the _answer section_. You know this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, I do. That doesn't mean I have to always post as an answer instead of a comment. Maybe I like giving other people a chance to post answers before I do.  It is not like I need the reputation points for answering.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Then don't answer but the comments section is not the proper place for answering the question. "I don't want the reputation points" is not a valid reason to bypass the peer review system and site model. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is being allocated with `new`, so there is nothing to `delete`. The `vector` will be destructed automatically when it goes out of scope when the function exits.